# Grabbing current DateTime using EF MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I want to apply a timestamp to my Entity Framework project. I have a class listed below. I hoped that this class would grab the current DateTime. But instead it provides me a field to enter my datetime. I want this to grab the current datetime.

```
 public class Answer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Answers {get; set;}
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public string Division { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }



    }
```

Below is the line of code that i know is wrong.

```
public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

i am a little unsure of how to go about this. I am new to entity and new to MVC.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could initialize it in the constructor e.g.

```
public class Answer
{
    public Answer()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    ...
}
```

However, I get the impression that your `Answer` class isn't actually an entity but a view model. For actual entities, what I tend to do with fixed/generated values like this is let the database populate the field with a default value e.g. `GetUtcDate()` and then in the EF designer set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property to `Computed` - that way when you pull down your entities the `CreatedDate` will be pre-populated. This gives you data integrity both ways as you won't be able to overwrite the field in the database either when pushing your data back up.

Then it's just a case of mapping your `Answer` entity to your `Answer` view model therefore nothing has to be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the DateCreated in the constructor -

```
public Answer()
{
  DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
}
```

And then, if you're using it in an MVC view, set the field to be hidden so it's not altered.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I took a little bit from both.  James you new exactly what i needed to do.  Mark you helped as well. But i needed to comment out the field to get it to work the way i wanted not  hide it because the validations still fire when hidden. But `DateTime.Now` was the format i was looking for so thank you for that!

Comment: @jackncoke just be wary about storing local date/times in the database, there are many pitfalls. However, it depends on the nature of your app. It's usually a good idea to store them as UTC & convert them back to local time when displaying.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the timestamp and also a potential modified date by overriding the SaveChanges() method on your context.

Quick example below.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
public class Answer : BaseEntity
{
    public String Answers { get; set; }
    public String Division { get; set; }
    public String Phone { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}

public class DB_Context : DbContext
{
    .....

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>();

        if (changeSet != null)
        {
            foreach (var added in changeSet.Where(x => x.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added))
            {
                added.Entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                added.Entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
            foreach (var modified in changeSet.Where(x => x.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified))
            {
                modified.Entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```